# php function to delete all files & folders older than 1 day

Tags: php

i am using this function and it works fine but only problem is it deletes root folder if folder is empty.

if all items are already deleted with previous cron and then again it is called then it will delete forder word. Any help will be great

```
rrmdir('/path/word');
function rrmdir($dir) 
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) 
    {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) 
        {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") 
            {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
         if (filemtime($dir."/".$object) <= time()-60*60*24) @unlink($dir."/".$object);

            }
        }
        reset($objects);
       rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove rmdir($dir); at last of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is that it depends on the intention of the caller. Should they pass in a directory and if so - should it remove this directory.  As the routine is called `rrmdir` I would sort of expect it to remove the directory I was passing in.

```
function rrmdir($dir)
{
    echo $dir.PHP_EOL;
    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object)
        {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..")
            {
                echo $object.'='.filetype($dir."/".$object).PHP_EOL;
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") {
                    rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
                    rmdir($dir);
                }
                if (filemtime($dir."/".$object) <= time()-60*60*24) unlink($dir."/".$object);

            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        //rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

I've moved the `rmdir` into the test for sub-directories.  It was previously removing all directories (including the one passed in).

Comment: these are temp files which are being created automatically & cleared automatically after 24 hours .if i add / even then PHP starts giving warning & does not delete files.i did not get ur few points. how You could automatically add the '/*'

Comment: I've updated the answer to try and stick with how you were calling it.  The rmdir is moved inside the test for subdirectories.

Comment: it can remove files but could not delete folders

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have decided to use if (is_dir_empty($dir)) { do nothing} else { rrmdir }